# Can Someone Kindly Provide The original Arabic Text Of This Narration?

Tags: source-identification, seerah

Question: Brothers! Can Anyone Provide The Original Arabic Version of This narration Of Umar Bin Al-Khataab in Arabic?
Salam Guys!

I need the following quote of Umar bin Al-Khataab (RA) in Arabic:-

It is said that Umar promised to strike the head of any man who would say that Muhammad died. Umar said: "He has not died but rather he has gone to his lord just as Moses went, remaining absent from his people for forty nights after which he has returned to them. By Allah, the messenger of Allah will indeed return just as Moses returned (to his people) and he will cut off the hands and legs of those men who claimed he has died."[38] Abu Bakr then publicly spoke to the community in the mosque, saying:
"Whoever worshiped Muhammad, let them know that Muhammad has died, and whoever worshiped Allah, let them know that Allah is alive and never dies."
I found the English version here:-

https://archive.org/stream/TheBiographyOfAbuBakrAsSiddeeq/TheBiographyOfAbuBakrAs-siddeeq#page/n199/mode/2up

But I Desperately Need The Original Arabic Version.

Thanks!

Comment: Your english book refers to **As-seerah An-Nabawiyyah, by Abu Shohbah (2/594)** which you can find in Arabic [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/9896/1149#p5). It is also quoted in many other works of seerah.

Answer (score -1):

your provided link mention its interpretation (tafseer) though these hadith were mentioned and they have Arabic text which you are actually looking for.

[Sahih Muslim 2348](https://sunnah.com/muslim/43/149)

[Sahih Muslim 2349a](https://sunnah.com/muslim/43/150)

[Sahih Muslim 2349b](https://sunnah.com/muslim/43/151)

[Sahih Muslim 2454](https://sunnah.com/muslim/44/148).

Comment: None of the provided sources covers the topic even partly.